# Insert into error table if the rows violates primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST 
(
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    C_status INT NOT NULL,
    SS VARCHAR(10),

    CONSTRAINT [PK_TBL] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC, [C_status ] ASC, [SS ] ASC)
)
```

Now I'm trying to insert some values into this table using

```
INSERT INTO SELECT ...
```

There will be duplicates in the data. How do I insert only the unique values in one table and duplicates in other table. For e.g, if I do the below

```
INSERT INTO TEST
SELECT '1','90','PARIS'
UNION ALL
SELECT '1','90','PARIS'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2','90','PARIS'
```

I want to insert `1st` row and `3rd` row in `TEST` and `2nd row` in `TEST_ERROR`. Is this possible with SQL query. My expected output is

`TEST`

| ID | C_STATUS | SS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 90 | PARIS |
| 2 | 90 | PARIS |

`TEST_ERROR`

| ID | C_STATUS | SS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 90 | PARIS |

I have tried something like below and it didn't work obviously

```
BEGIN TRY
insert into test
SELECT '1','90','PARIS'
UNION ALL
SELECT '1','90','PARIS'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2','90','PARIS'
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
insert into test
.........
END CATCH
```

Comment: Group your incoming data to remove duplicates from the incoming data, and use a not exists to avoid inserting duplicate data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger on the `TEST`. Use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to identify those duplicates and only insert one of the row into `TEST` and those duplicates into `TEST_ERROR`

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_TEST 
ON TEST
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TEST (ID, C_status, SS)
    SELECT  ID, C_status, SS
    FROM
    (
        SELECT  ID, C_status, SS
                RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID, C_status, SS ORDER BY ID)
        FROM    INSERTED
    ) i
    WHERE   i.RN    = 1

    INSERT INTO TEST_ERROR (ID, C_status, SS)
    SELECT  ID, C_status, SS
    FROM
    (
        SELECT  ID, C_status, SS, 
                RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID, C_status, SS ORDER BY ID)
        FROM    INSERTED
    ) i
    WHERE   i.RN    > 1
END
```

Answer (score 1):

When you insert as a batch, it is all or nothing operation. You cannot specifically send error rows to error file. If you want to do at row level, you have to have CURSOR to send error rows.

but, You can apply ROW_NUMBER() and filter duplicate data and send to error table.

```sql
--duplicate data 
;with cte_alldata(id, c_status, ss) as
(
SELECT '1','90','PARIS'
UNION ALL
SELECT '1','90','PARIS'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2','90','PARIS'
)
, cte_distinctdata as
(
SELECT *, row_number() over(partition by id, c_status, ss order by id) as rnk
FROM cte_alldata
)
INSERT INTO Error_Table
SELECT id, c_status, ss from cte_distinctdata where rnk >1
```

| id | c_status | ss |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 90 | PARIS |